# Using Styles from an External Database in React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, axios, jsx

**Use case:**

We're getting styles such as color hex codes and sizes pulled in from an external database (mySQL) and pulling those in via axios.

What is the easiest way to pass those variables from a Javascript file into our CSS styles in React?

We know we can do this in React, but we'd like to make it more scalable using class-based and component-based CSS.

Here's an example of our axios get:

```
axios.get(`/landingPage/${ customerId }`)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    this.setState({
      databaseStuff: mapToProps(response.data),
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
 }
```

This is putting all of our properties from the database into this.props so that we can access them in the jsx. We now just need to get them into the styles.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should as start you have a basic default styling using https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops for each component like :

```
Hello.defaultProps = {
color: 'blue'
}
```

and then you can apply changes using className.

```
<UserComponent className={props.databaseStuff.userClass}/>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what `userClass` is doing in your example? I think I'm missing something.

Comment: I don't want to miss lead you if you are pulling a single value from the database you can use the props.databaseStuff . in my example I expected you that you are pulling a json string that has different values in it thats why I did put userClass as an attribute.

Comment: This is very helpful feedback but I think our use case is unique. We don't have class names coming from the database. We only have hex codes and branding guidelines coming front the database so we have to apply them ourselves based on the json object.